# Handles and carryon baggage sizing

Tags: luggage

When measuring the dimensions of a piece of luggage, do you measure the height with the handle fully extended or collapsed?

Answer (score 6):

Measure it in the configuration it will be in when stored in the airplane.

Presumably you'll collapse the handle before putting it in the bin, so that's the measurement to use here.